# How to define a function of probability addition formula

Tags: probability-or-statistics

In probability theory, the addition formula of any event is as follows:

$$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A B)$$

$$\begin{aligned}
P\left(A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup \cdots \cup A_{n}\right)=& \sum_{i=1}^{n} P\left(A_{i}\right)-\sum_{1 \leqslant i<j \leqslant n} P\left(A_{i} A_{j}\right) \\
&+\sum_{1 \leqslant i<j<k \leqslant n} P\left(A_{i} A_{j} A_{k}\right)+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1} P\left(A_{1} A_{2} \cdots A_{n}\right)
\end{aligned}$$

Let's take `n = 5` as an example, but I have encountered problems:

```
n = 5; 
Sum[P[A[i]], {i, 1, n}] - 
 Sum[P[A[i]*A[j]], {Inequality[1, LessEqual, i, Less, j, LessEqual, 
         n], n}] + 
 Sum[P[A[i]*A[j]*A[k]], {Inequality[1, LessEqual, i, Less, j, Less, k, 
         LessEqual, n], n}] - Sum[P[A[i]*A[j]*A[k]*A[l]], 
     {Inequality[1, LessEqual, i, Less, j, Less, k, Less, l, 
    LessEqual, n], n}] + 
   P[A[i]*A[j]*A[k]*A[l]*A[m]]
```

I want to know what concise and efficient method can be used to define this function.

Comment: Think of `n = 5; Sum[P[A[i]*A[j]], {j, 1, n}, {i, 1, j - 1}]` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PExpand[expr_] := Module[{A, B, expr1, f, H}, f = expr /. H_[___] -> H;
  expr1 = expr /. f[A___] -> A;
  f /@ Expand[expr1 //. A_ || B_ :> A (-B) + A + B] /. 
   f[-B__] :> -f[Times[B]]]
PExpand[P[Or @@ Array[Subscript[A, #1] &, 5]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    list = {P1, P2, P3, P4, P5};
Total[Flatten@
  Table[(-1)^(k - 1) Times @@@ Subsets[list, {k}], {k, 1, 5}]]
```

**Update-1** Thanks to the suggestions in comments.

```
list = {A1, A2, A3, A4, A5};
Sum[Total[(-1)^(k - 1) P /@ And @@@ Subsets[list, {k}]], {k, 1, 5}]
```

**Update-2**

need to be updated later :)

Comment: Although you've nicely condensed the code to what the OP asked, I wonder if replacing `Times` by `P` or `Pr` would display the intent of the formula better (as P1, P2,... represents events rather than probabilities).